# Programaticly Limiting number of rows for mysql database using VB.net

Tags: mysql, vb.net, limit, rows, webmethod

Good day I have written a function that needs to limit the number of employees that can be added to the database.

```
    <WebMethod()>
Public Function EmployeeSubToken()
    Dim cmd As New SqlCommand("Select vchSubscriptionType FROM BillingInfo", con)
    Dim subtype = "vchSubscriptionType"
    Dim Token


    Select Case subtype
        Case subtype = "Bronze"
            Token = 1
        Case subtype = "Silver"
            Token = 2
        Case subtype = "Gold"
            Token = 3
        Case subtype = "Platinum"
            Token = 4
    End Select

    Dim cmd2

    Select Case Token
        Case Token = 1
            cmd2 = New SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM Subscribers.dtEmployment Where ROWNUM <= 5 LIMIT 5")
        Case Token = 2
            cmd2 = New SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM Subscribers.dtEmployment Where ROWNUM <= 5 LIMIT 10")
        Case Token = 3
            cmd2 = New SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM Subscribers.dtEmployment Where ROWNUM <= 5 LIMIT 25")
        Case Token = 4
            cmd2 = New SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM Subscribers.dtEmployment")
    End Select

End Function
```

Does anyone know how If this is the correct way of doing it? if it is not how would I accomplish this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you want to limit the inserts, have a function that will query your database and return a count of rows,  `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM dtEmployment ;` then just use a simple if,

```
if(dtEmploymentCount < MydesiredCount) then
'Do My Insert

else
'Return your message (Maximum amount of entries reached)
end If
```

Comment: Thank you, that actually looks like a more efficient way of doing it so basically instead of doing this as a separate function combine it to when i do the actual insert?

Comment: you will have a function to find the amount of rows in the table. that variable will be `dtEmploymentCount `. `MydesiredCount` will be the amount of rows allowed in the table. you will then have your insert inside the if statement.

Comment: in terms of clean coding create a method for your insert and call it from inside the if statement.  Ideally each method or function should only do one thing. it helps make code more readable and more maintainable

Comment: Clear and easy to understand thank you @Kevin very much busy implementing it now.

Answer (score 0):

maybe TOP(5) your looking for.

is there any order to the rows your returning, i.e. does it matter which 5 are returned?

Comment: Im actually unclear as to what I should set the where clause as it does not matter what is returned as long as I can limit the amount of rows that can be added